# Can I remove all maps containing key?

Tags: key-bindings, autocmd, leader, plugin-c.vim

I have a plugin (c.vim) which includes a lot of maps (all with leader key). I changed my leader key to space, which I like, but the problem is that the maps also apply to insert mode. I would like to disable all imaps containing `<Space>`, so space in insert doesn't cause a delay (and sometimes a command).

I tried `:iunmap`ing specific maps using what I saw in `:imap`, but that said `E31: No such mapping`.

I also tried using `.vim/after/plugin/map.vim` and `autocmd VimEnter * imapclear`, neither of which worked.

Comment: What is the `c.vim` plugin?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your insert mode mappings are filetype specific then `.vim/after/plugin/map.vim` and `autocmd VimEnter * imapclear` would not work as they are executed before fitetype creates them. Also `imapclear` deletes all insert mode mappings including default ones.

You can try to apply `imapclear <buffer>` on bufread/filetype event though:

**using after/ftplugin**

create `.vim/after/ftplugin/c.vim`:

```
imapclear <buffer>
```

**using autocommands**

put it into your vimrc:

```
augroup cvim_imapclear | au!
    au BufRead,BufNewFile *.c imapclear <buffer>
augroup end
```

PS, although I would challenge your `c.vim` plugin if it has other means of tuning it/turning those off.

PPS, what is the `:imap` output? Can you see those mappings?

Comment: `imap` example `i <Space>hm @<C-C>:call C_Help("m")<CR>`.

Comment: There is smth wrong with this c.vim. It should provide non-intrusive buffer local insert mode mappings.

Answer (score 3):

You can try to analyze the result of `split(execute('imap <buffer> <space>'), "\n")`

From there, keep only the second field (IIRC). => `->map({k,v -> split(v)[1]})`, and generate the clearing commands, => prefer `->map({k,v -> 'iunmap <buffer> '.split(v)[1]})`

And finally `->execute()`.

**TL;DR**

```
:call execute('imap <buffer> <space>')
\ ->split("\n")
\ ->map({k,v -> 'iunmap <buffer> '.split(v)[1]})
\ ->execute()
```

I guess it should be done in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/c/clear-imaps.vim`

PS: I don't user (local/)leader in insert mode mappings in [lh-cpp](https://github.com/LucHermitte/lh-cpp) ^^'

Comment: Could you loop over `maparg` results, unmapping them?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, the problem is that `maparg()`  returns only one result and it has to receive the exact key sequence. `maparg('<space>', 'i')`  won't return anything in OP's case. `mapcheck()`  will work on a partial match, but again, only a single result will be returned. They can't be exploited to answer OP's question.

Comment: Maybe i was looking at the wrong function, so it’s mapcheck that does partial matches. But if you do something like `while mapcheck != empty | iunmap` (pseudocode)? Surely that could give you all of them?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble. May be. But as I don't like loops (slow and painful to debug), I prefer the  functional approach. ^^' Beside, as we cannot have ` while (m = mapcheck(...); !empty(m))`  in Vimscript language, the loops will be clumsy with repeated lines.

Comment: for sure it’s clumsy, and the functional is usually better—but parsing the output seems liable to break unexpectedly. Eh. Maybe ill try to write up an answer using it, just as an alternative.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble There are risks indeed: 1. I don't know whether newlines can appears in a mapping. I don't see how. 2. The output format of `:map`  may change in the future. In an ideal world `mapcheck()` would have another parameter to return all matches.

Answer (score 1):

This should work to clear all Insert-mode mappings starting with space:

```
let l:map = mapcheck(' ', 'i')
while !empty(l:map)
  execute 'iunmap' l:map
  let l:map = mapcheck(' ', 'i')
endwhile
```

Unfortunately, there is no way to restrict `mapcheck` to buffer-local mappings only; however, the ugly loop *does* let us sidestep parsing command output, which may be brittle and break if the output ever changes or contains something unexpected.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up combining bits of solutions provided by [Luc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/626/luc-hermitte) and [Maxim](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/9333/maxim-kim), ending up with the following in my `.vimrc`:

```
" clear all mappings starting with space in insert mode
" based on https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26385/40274
" and https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/26384/40274
function! ClearInsertLeaders() abort
        let s:mappings = execute('imap <space>')
        \ ->split('\n')
        \ ->map({k,v -> split(v)[1]})
        for mapping in s:mappings
                " needed in case of no mappings
                if mapping != 'mapping'
                        execute('iunmap '.mapping)
                endif
        endfor
endfunction
    
augroup clear_insert_leaders
        autocmd!
        autocmd BufRead,BufNewFile * call ClearInsertLeaders()
augroup END
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!